# Spring boot @Configuration order

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have two configuration classes, **ConfigA** & **ConfigB** , Is there anyway that I can load those configuration classes in the order, I want **ConfigB** to be loaded first then load the class **ConfigA**. Please help me.

Comment: those classes are annotated with @Configuration

Comment: Use `@Order` annotation or `@DependsOn` annotation to create dependency.

Comment: @DhavalGajjar- I have tried both the option , but not working.

Answer (score 1):

If the `@Configuration` classes are component-scanned you cannot reliably control their order so the first step is to ensure that they aren't component scanned. You can then use `@Import` to import the configuration classes. They will be processed in the order in which you list them in the `@Import` annotation.